# Passing an object to $.ajax succes function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently working on a project with javascript and jquery.
I'm using a `$.ajax` call to ask the server for some data. This call is being made within an object I created.

On success, I want to update the data members of such object with the data recieved. It looks something like so:

```
function Caller() { 
    this.data1 = 0; 
    this.data2 = 1; 
    this.makeRequest = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "some url",
            data: somedata,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function ( data ) {
                // update data
            }
        });
    };
};
```

For passing the original object (`Caller`) to the succes function, I've tried the following:

```
function Caller() { 
    this.data1 = 0; 
    this.data2 = 1; 
    this.makeRequest = function () {
        var _this = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: "some url",
            data: somedata,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function ( data ) {
                // update data
                _this.data1 = data.data1;
                _this.data2 = data.data2;
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Then I tried:

```
function Caller() { 
    this.data1 = 0; 
    this.data2 = 1; 
    this.makeRequest = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "some url",
            data: somedata,
            dataType: "json",
            _this: this,
            success: function ( data ) {
                // update data
                var _this = this._this
                _this.data1 = data.data1;
                _this.data2 = data.data2;
            }
        });
    };
};
```

And then:

```
function Caller() { 
    this.data1 = 0; 
    this.data2 = 1; 
    this.makeRequest = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "some url",
            data: somedata,
            dataType: "json",
            context: this,
            success: function ( data ) {
                // update data
                this.data1 = data.data1;
                this.data2 = data.data2;
            }
        });
    };
};
```

In all the cases above, it seems that a copy of the object, rather than the original one, is being pass to the function, so the original values are not 
changed.
Is there a way to change the originals values of the object or pass the original one? I hope you can help me, i've stuck with this for a while.

Comment: where is the call to the makeRequest function?

Comment: Maybe you could try to pass [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as value of `makeRequest` and `success`. Arrow functions don’t introduce context, so `this` would refer to the context of outer scope, instance of `Caller`.

Comment: *"In all the cases above, it seems that a copy of the object, rather than the original one, is being pass to the function, so the original values are not changed."* **prove it.** In all three of those cases you should be accessing the same object. I assume you're actually trying to return data from an asynchronous callback, which simply isn't possible.

Comment: Have you tried var `_this = $(this);` in your first example?

Comment: Dude, jQuery will not help here :D.

Comment: Instead of a Function Caller, did you try and made it into an object instead? I think the problem here would be the closure.

Comment: Your first code snippet should be working just fine - I just tested in console. I suggest you check that you are not overwriting those values somewhere else in the code and that you do have 200 response from server. Also, make sure that the data returned is actually what you expect it to be, ie. not an empty object or empty string.

Answer (score -2):

If you send a request to another site, you must do

```
crossDomain: true
```

or
If you want to do data return, you must do

```
async: true
```

Example:

```
var data_1 = 0;
ajax success function data_1 = data.data_1
return data_1;
```

Comment: it's actually `async: false`, but you should never do that.